# query execution x100 slower on prod than locally

Tags: postgresql

So I have identical databases with identical set of data, one is on production instance with 4GbRam another is i docker image.
I'm running same query:

```
select * from product p
inner join product_manufacturers pm on pm.product_id = p.id 
inner join manufacturers m on pm.manufacturer_id = m.id 
inner join brand b on p.brand_id = b.id 
inner join tags t on t.product_id = p.id 
inner join groups g on g.manufacturer_id = pm.id 
inner join group_options gp on g.id = gp.group_id 
inner join images i on i.product_id = p.id 
where pm.enabled = true 
and pm.available = true 
and pm.launched = true 
and p.available = true 
and p.enabled = true
and p.id in (49, 77, 6, 12, 36)
order by b.id
```

Locally  query execution time is 4 seconds and returned rows amount are 120k.
But on production execution time is 8 minutes and amount of returned rows are the same (as tables are identical).

What can be the issue, as I already told databases structure the same (same indexes etc.) and they have identical data, so why the execution time so different.... Also, when I'm runing the query on production directly through `pgsql` and storing result to the file, postgres execute query instantly but process of storing data to the file taking 8 minutes... what can be wrong with my instance???

I know a lot of unknowns here, but it's all what I have at the moment.

Local explain:

```
Nested Loop  (cost=5.83..213.82 rows=1399 width=1820) (actual time=4.861..2352.400 rows=119503 loops=1)
  Join Filter: (pm.product_id = t.product_id)
  Buffers: shared hit=42646 read=85
  ->  Nested Loop  (cost=5.55..107.33 rows=202 width=1797) (actual time=4.548..280.433 rows=12743 loops=1)
        Buffers: shared hit=4420 read=82
        ->  Nested Loop  (cost=5.26..81.32 rows=30 width=1763) (actual time=3.508..44.939 rows=950 loops=1)
              Buffers: shared hit=931 read=38
              ->  Nested Loop  (cost=4.98..77.05 rows=7 width=1697) (actual time=2.768..23.855 rows=166 loops=1)
                    Buffers: shared hit=436 read=35
                    ->  Nested Loop  (cost=4.71..75.14 rows=4 width=1677) (actual time=2.196..15.537 rows=83 loops=1)
                          Buffers: shared hit=195 read=26
                          ->  Nested Loop  (cost=4.56..74.36 rows=4 width=1399) (actual time=2.155..13.079 rows=83 loops=1)
                                Buffers: shared hit=30 read=25
                                ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.27..40.11 rows=3 width=646) (actual time=1.803..3.986 rows=5 loops=1)
                                      Join Filter: (p.brand_id = b.id)
                                      Rows Removed by Join Filter: 158
                                      Buffers: shared hit=17 read=4
                                      ->  Index Scan using product_pkey on product p  (cost=0.27..34.93 rows=3 width=407) (actual time=0.830..1.995 rows=5 loops=1)
                                            Index Cond: (id = ANY ('{49,77,6,12,36}'::integer[]))
                                            Filter: (available AND enabled)
                                            Buffers: shared hit=16 read=2
                                      ->  Materialize  (cost=0.00..3.57 rows=38 width=239) (actual time=0.066..0.254 rows=33 loops=5)
                                            Buffers: shared hit=1 read=2
                                            ->  Seq Scan on brand b  (cost=0.00..3.38 rows=38 width=239) (actual time=0.298..0.461 rows=40 loops=1)
                                                  Buffers: shared hit=1 read=2
                                ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on product_manufacturers pm  (cost=4.29..11.41 rows=1 width=753) (actual time=0.674..1.615 rows=17 loops=5)
                                      Recheck Cond: (product_id = p.id)
                                      Filter: (available AND launched)
                                      Rows Removed by Filter: 5
                                      Heap Blocks: exact=21
                                      Buffers: shared hit=13 read=21
                                      ->  Bitmap Index Scan on idx_e093f35a40e556f5  (cost=0.00..4.29 rows=2 width=0) (actual time=0.019..0.020 rows=27 loops=5)
                                            Index Cond: (product_id = p.id)
                                            Buffers: shared hit=9 read=1
                          ->  Index Scan using manufacturer_pkey on manufacturers m  (cost=0.14..0.20 rows=1 width=278) (actual time=0.011..0.011 rows=1 loops=83)
                                Index Cond: (id = pm.manufacturer_id)
                                Filter: enabled
                                Buffers: shared hit=165 read=1
                    ->  Index Scan using idx_237d25c5d3e1ebb8 on groups g  (cost=0.28..0.46 rows=2 width=20) (actual time=0.055..0.067 rows=2 loops=83)
                          Index Cond: (manufacturer_id = pm.id)
                          Buffers: shared hit=241 read=9
              ->  Index Scan using idx_4a5244b740e556f5 on icons i  (cost=0.28..0.57 rows=4 width=66) (actual time=0.021..0.053 rows=6 loops=166)
                    Index Cond: (product_id = pm.product_id)
                    Buffers: shared hit=495 read=3
        ->  Index Scan using group_options_unique_idx on group_options gp  (cost=0.29..0.80 rows=7 width=34) (actual time=0.023..0.104 rows=13 loops=950)
              Index Cond: (group_id = g.id)
              Buffers: shared hit=3489 read=44
  ->  Index Scan using idx_7edc9c5340e556f5 on tags t  (cost=0.28..0.45 rows=6 width=19) (actual time=0.008..0.057 rows=9 loops=12743)
        Index Cond: (product_id = i.product_id)
        Buffers: shared hit=38226 read=3
Planning Time: 65.124 ms
Execution Time: 2926.918 ms
```

and here is production explain:

```
Nested Loop  (cost=1.81..201.75 rows=1344 width=1760) (actual time=0.170..115.850 rows=119503 loops=1)
  Join Filter: (pm.product_id = t.product_id)
  Buffers: shared hit=43045
  ->  Nested Loop  (cost=1.53..88.32 rows=211 width=1737) (actual time=0.145..13.585 rows=12743 loops=1)
        Buffers: shared hit=4816
        ->  Nested Loop  (cost=1.25..64.37 rows=29 width=1703) (actual time=0.120..2.492 rows=950 loops=1)
              Buffers: shared hit=954
              ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.97..60.22 rows=7 width=1637) (actual time=0.103..1.468 rows=166 loops=1)
                    Buffers: shared hit=456
                    ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.69..58.32 rows=4 width=1617) (actual time=0.084..0.950 rows=83 loops=1)
                          Join Filter: (p.brand_id = b.id)
                          Rows Removed by Join Filter: 598
                          Buffers: shared hit=206
                          ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.69..53.64 rows=4 width=1411) (actual time=0.072..0.705 rows=83 loops=1)
                                Buffers: shared hit=205
                                ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.55..52.62 rows=5 width=1153) (actual time=0.058..0.338 rows=83 loops=1)
                                      Buffers: shared hit=39
                                      ->  Index Scan using product_pkey on product p  (cost=0.27..22.60 rows=4 width=403) (actual time=0.039..0.072 rows=5 loops=1)
                                            Index Cond: (id = ANY ('{49,77,6,12,36}'::integer[]))
                                            Filter: (available AND enabled)
                                            Buffers: shared hit=16
                                      ->  Index Scan using idx_e093f35a40e556f5 on product_manufacturers pm  (cost=0.28..7.50 rows=1 width=750) (actual time=0.012..0.043 rows=17 loops=5)
                                            Index Cond: (product_id = p.id)
                                            Filter: (available AND launched)
                                            Rows Removed by Filter: 5
                                            Buffers: shared hit=23
                                ->  Index Scan using manufacturer_pkey on manufacturer m  (cost=0.14..0.20 rows=1 width=258) (actual time=0.003..0.003 rows=1 loops=83)
                                      Index Cond: (id = pm.manufacturer_id)
                                      Filter: enabled
                                      Buffers: shared hit=166
                          ->  Materialize  (cost=0.00..2.56 rows=37 width=206) (actual time=0.000..0.001 rows=8 loops=83)
                                Buffers: shared hit=1
                                ->  Seq Scan on brand b  (cost=0.00..2.37 rows=37 width=206) (actual time=0.006..0.012 rows=27 loops=1)
                                      Buffers: shared hit=1
                    ->  Index Scan using idx_237d25c5d3e1ebb8 on groups g  (cost=0.28..0.45 rows=2 width=20) (actual time=0.003..0.004 rows=2 loops=83)
                          Index Cond: (manufacturer_id = pm.id)
                          Buffers: shared hit=250
              ->  Index Scan using idx_4a5244b740e556f5 on icons i  (cost=0.28..0.55 rows=4 width=66) (actual time=0.002..0.003 rows=6 loops=166)
                    Index Cond: (product_id = pm.product_id)
                    Buffers: shared hit=498
        ->  Index Scan using group_options_unique_idx on group_options gp  (cost=0.29..0.76 rows=7 width=34) (actual time=0.003..0.007 rows=13 loops=950)
              Index Cond: (group_id = g.id)
              Buffers: shared hit=3862
  ->  Index Scan using idx_7edc9c5340e556f5 on tags t  (cost=0.28..0.46 rows=6 width=19) (actual time=0.003..0.004 rows=9 loops=12743)
        Index Cond: (product_id = i.product_id)
        Buffers: shared hit=38229
Planning Time: 11.001 ms
Execution Time: 129.339 ms
```

Regarding indexes, I did not add any specific indexes yet, this query used in background and I did not try to optimize it yet as 3-4 seconds was allowable time but here it is, all the indexes I have:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX product_pkey ON product USING btree (id);
CREATE INDEX idx_2645e26644f5d008 ON product USING btree (brand_id);
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX brand_pkey ON brand USING btree (id);
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX icon_pkey ON icons USING btree (id);
CREATE INDEX idx_4a5244b740e556f5 ON icons USING btree (product_id);
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX tags_pkey ON tags USING btree (id);
CREATE INDEX idx_7edc9c5340e556f5 ON tags USING btree (product_id);
CREATE INDEX tag_value_index ON tags USING btree (value);
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX manufacturer_pkey ON manufacturers USING btree (id);
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX groups_pkey ON groups_pkey USING btree (id);
CREATE INDEX idx_237d25c5d3e1ebb8 ON groups USING btree (manufacturer_id);
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX group_options_pkey ON group_options USING btree (id);
CREATE INDEX idx_2a964c28de23a8e3 ON group_options USING btree (group_id);
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX group_options_unique_idx ON group_options USING btree (group_id, option_id);
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX product_manufacturer_pkey ON product_manufacturers USING btree (id);
CREATE INDEX idx_e093f35a40e556f5 ON product_manufacturers USING btree (product_id);
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX manufacturer_unique_idx ON product_manufacturers USING btree (manufacturer_id, product_id);
CREATE INDEX idx_e093f35ad3e1ebb8 ON product_manufacturers USING btree (manufacturer_id)
```

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add both [execution plans](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/using-explain.html) generated using **`explain (analyze, buffers, format text)`** (_not_ just a "simple" explain) as  [formatted text](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) and make sure you preserve the indention of the plan. Paste the text, then put `\`\`\`` on the line before the plan and on a line after the plan. Please also include complete `create index` statements for all indexes as well.

Comment: If storing data is slow, I'd guess your PC is much more powerful than production machine - 4GB RAM seems pretty low for a production. Check out and compare the hardware, especially SSD/HDD and R/W speed

Comment: Have you run `Analyze` on the prod instance? Also are you saving to file on local instance also? Are you using `psql`(it is not pgsql) on the local instance also?

Comment: done, I have added `analyze` statements.

Comment: the production query is about 20 times _faster_ than locally.

Comment: You have not answered my other questions though.

Comment: Apparently reading 120,000 rows across the network is slow.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name well, that what I told, it's running instantly, but I do not not believe that sending few megabytes of data across the network can take 8 minutes....??? in such a case each query on production for me would take a lot of time, but othe.smaller queries working fast.... can it be the issue with iops???

Comment: @AdrianKlaver yes i did, I run both instances, local and prod through the same tests. First I run query thrrough Dbeaver without offset on both (localy 4 seconds, prod 8 minutes), afterwards I run both through with using of `psql` and saving result to the file